# What is the product and mechanism of reducing a cyclohexanone derrivative with LAH?

Tags: synthesis, organic-reduction

I've been trying to figure out the product and mechanism of the reaction pictured below for a while now:
[image]

I'm fairly sure that the first step is the reduction of the ketone by LAH, which results in a negative charge on the oxygen, that then forms a salt with the positively charged lithium. If this was just cyclohexanone, the acidic workup would simply yield a cyclohexanol.
However, from the given chemical formula of the product, I can tell that additional reactions/rearrangements must be happening: The educt has the formula C<sub>20</sub>H<sub>20</sub>O<sub>2</sub>, so the product must have one O, two Cs and 4 Hs less than the educt. I'm pretty sure that this ammounts to the loss of the ethoxy group, which would in turn mean that the product gains one H from some other source (since it loses 5 Hs from the ethoxy group, but has 16 Hs).

This is about as far as I got, and haven't yet found a reaction mechanism that would yield a product with the correct formula.
Here's one of my attempts, with the idea being that it's sort of analogous to how LAH reduces Esters first to Aldehydes and then Alcohols.
[image]
The problem here is that there's two Hs too many. I'm also very unsure about the validity of the electron pushing arrows.

What is the correct mechanism in this case?

Comment: I think there's an error in there.

Comment: LiAlH4 reduces the ketone to alcohol. The acidic workup hydrolyses the enol ether to ketone AND dehydrates the alcohol to alkene forming the enone.